# How do I check whether night mode was turned on or off

Tags: java, android, android-dark-theme

I don't want to know what is the current going on mode (dark or light) in my android device. I want to know if the mode was switched at the time my android activity was running. How do I put a check for it? Is there any in-built method for it? If not, then how to do it? I am using Java and I am a beginner.